# How to fix error: cannot implicitly convert int to string

Tags: c#

I just need some help. I am making a basic calculator.

I want my calculator to have an error message when the user tries to input a string or a decimal value. But when i finish coding, I cannot declare my int variables (`firstNum2`, `secondNum2` & `thirdNum2`) because of the error said

> cannot implicitly convert int to string

**Code**

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter A First Num");
firstNum = Console.ReadLine();
char[] firstNumArray = firstNum.ToCharArray();
int length = firstNum.Length;

for (int a = 0; a < length; a++)
{
   if (!(firstNum[a]
            .Equals('0') || firstNum[a]
            .Equals('1') || firstNum[a]
            .Equals('2') || firstNum[a]
            .Equals('3') || firstNum[a]
            .Equals('4') || firstNum[a]
            .Equals('5') || firstNum[a]
            .Equals('6') || firstNum[a]
            .Equals('7') || firstNum[a]
            .Equals('9')))

   {


      if (firstNumArray[a]
         .Equals('.'))
      {
         Console.WriteLine("You just inputted a decimal value. Enter another value");
         goto Start1;
      }
      else if (firstNum == "EXIT")
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Kdot");
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
      else if (int.TryParse(firstNum, out firstNum1))
      {

         Console.WriteLine("Your number is " + firstNum1);
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("You just inputted a string/ char value. Try again.");

         goto Start1;
      }

   }
}

Start2:

Console.WriteLine("Enter A Second Num");
secondNum = Console.ReadLine();
char[] secondNumArray = secondNum.ToCharArray();
int length1 = secondNum.Length;

for (int b = 0; b < length1; b++)
{
   if (!(secondNum[b]
            .Equals('0') || secondNum[b]
            .Equals('1') || secondNum[b]
            .Equals('2') || secondNum[b]
            .Equals('3') || secondNum[b]
            .Equals('4') || secondNum[b]
            .Equals('5') || secondNum[b]
            .Equals('6') || secondNum[b]
            .Equals('7') || secondNum[b]
            .Equals('9')))
   {

      if (secondNumArray[b]
         .Equals('.'))
      {
         Console.WriteLine("You just inputted a decimal value. Enter another value");
         goto Start2;
      }
      else if (secondNum == "EXIT")
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Kdot");
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
      else if (int.TryParse(secondNum, out secondNum1))
      {

         Console.WriteLine("Your number is " + secondNum1);
         secondNum2 = Convert.ToInt32(secondNum1);

      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("You just inputted a string/ char value. Try again.");

         goto Start2;
      }

   }
}

Start3:
Console.WriteLine("Enter A Third Num");
thirdNum = Console.ReadLine();
char[] thirdNumArray = thirdNum.ToCharArray();
int length2 = thirdNum.Length;

for (int c = 0; c < length1; c++)
{
   if (!(thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('0') || thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('1') || thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('2') || thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('3') || thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('4') || thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('5') || thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('6') || thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('7') || thirdNum[c]
            .Equals('9')))
   {

      if (thirdNumArray[c]
         .Equals('.'))
      {
         Console.WriteLine("You just inputted a decimal value. Enter another value");
         goto Start3;
      }
      else if (thirdNum == "EXIT")
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Kdot");
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
      else if (int.TryParse(thirdNum, out thirdNum1))
      {

         Console.WriteLine("Your number is " + thirdNum1);
         thirdNum2 = Convert.ToInt32(thirdNum1);
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("You just inputted a string/ char value. Try again.");

         goto Start3;
      }

   }
}

//here the error occurs

sum = firstNum2 + secondNum2 + thirdNum2;
diff = firstNum2 - secondNum2 - thirdNum2;
prod = firstNum2 * secondNum2 * thirdNum2;
quo = firstNum2 / secondNum2 / thirdNum2;
mod = firstNum2 % secondNum2 % thirdNum2;


Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.WriteLine(diff);
Console.WriteLine(prod);
Console.WriteLine(quo);
Console.WriteLine(mod);
```

Answer (score 2):

You had so many problems with this, essentially (and I couldn't tell where) one of your results was actually a string and not an int. i.e `sum`, `diff`, etc...

However even if that was the case, there were many other subtle issues.

First thing you need to look up is [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

> In software engineering, don't repeat yourself (DRY) is a principle of
> software development aimed at reducing repetition of software
> patterns, replacing it with abstractions, or repetition of the same
> data, using data normalization to avoid redundancy.

The second thing is it's very unusual to use `goto` statements. Use a while loop instead, in this case I just made an endless loop.

Let's make a method to handle input:

```
// returning false signifies exit 
public static bool EnterNumber(out int result)
{
   result = 0;

   // read from the console
   var line = Console.ReadLine();
   while (true)
   {
      // if its exit return false
      if (line == "EXIT")
         return false;

      // it's an int yay!!!! return true
      if (int.TryParse(line, out result))
         return true;

      // it's a decimal, underscore means just discard the value
      if (decimal.TryParse(line, out _))
         Console.WriteLine("You just inputted a decimal value. Enter another value");
      else
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Try again.");
      line = Console.ReadLine();
   }  
}
```

Then you can simply just use it and check the results:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter first number");

   // this is not quite DRY, however it is easy to read
   if (!EnterNumber(out var firstNum))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Kdot");
      Console.ReadKey();
      return;
   }

   Console.WriteLine("Enter second number");
   if (!EnterNumber(out var secondNum))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Kdot");
      Console.ReadKey();
      return;
   }

   Console.WriteLine("Enter third number");
   if (!EnterNumber(out var thirddNum))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Kdot");
      Console.ReadKey();
      return;
   }

   Console.WriteLine($"Addition = {firstNum + secondNum + thirddNum}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Subtraction = {firstNum - secondNum - thirddNum}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Multiplication = {firstNum * secondNum * thirddNum}");
   // you need to cast int to double otherwise you will get unexpected results
   Console.WriteLine($"Division = {(double)firstNum /(double) secondNum / (double)thirddNum}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Modulo = {firstNum % secondNum % thirddNum}");
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**:

```
Enter first number
test
Invalid Input. Try again.
4.4
You just inputted a decimal value. Enter another value
1
Enter second number
2
Enter third number
3
Addition = 6
Subtraction = -4
Multiplication = 6
Division = 0.166666666666667
Modulo = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definitely thank you for the rest of my life. I'm actually an amateur programmer and I would like to thank you for pointing out my mistakes and suggesting me some pivotal principles of programming thanks a lot